# Flutter: Sign in with google access token on multiple devices

Tags: flutter, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement a google calendar sync mechanism in my app.

Currently added the google_sign_in package to get the access token. But it doesn't give a refresh token.

I've red in the documentation that the "signInSilently()" method should auto refresh the token.

But my app should work device independent (if the user uses multiple devices).
I guess the "signInSilently()" method is device dependent?

So is there a solution that's possible on client side?

I already tried this code (on client Flutter) to get a refresh token, but didn't succeed in using it to get a access token.

```
     final url = Uri.parse(
          'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp?key=xxx');

 final response = await http.post(url,
          headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
          body: jsonEncode({
            'postBody': 'id_token=$idToken&providerId=google.com',
            'requestUri': 'http://localhost',
            'returnIdpCredential': true,
            'returnSecureToken': true
          }));
```

Comment: Signin is authentication what you need is authorization.